# Bash script returning command not found, when setting the PATH

Tags: linux, bash

I am very new to Linux and Bash scripting. Also my first question on stackoverflow.

I am trying to create a bash script which I want to use from any directory.
So far this is what I did

Created a simple bash file first

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "This is a bash script"
exit 0
```

I set the permissions for execute using `chmod +x myfilename.sh`

And then I edited the **.profile** file under **~/.profile**

Added the line `"export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bash_course/scripts"`

After that I ran the command `source ~/.profile`

Now I tried to run `myfilename` from the terminal, but it returns **Command not found.**

Any idea what could have gone wrong?

I checked the path of my bash and it is `/usr/bin/bash`

If I run `./myfilename.sh` from file path, it is working. But I am trying to run from other directories.

*FYI : I am doing all of this on a WSL*

Comment: Since the file is called `myfilename.sh`, you run it with `myfilename.sh`, not `myfilename`.

Comment: That doesn't work either. The intent was to create my own command. i,e without even having to append **.sh** on the command.

Comment: A suggestion: Give a script an extension when "storing" it, but remove the extension when deploying it somewhere in `$PATH`. Also `.bash` is better than `.sh` as an extension for a bash script.

Comment: Actually I found the issue.

Comment: `/usr/bin/bash` might need to be `/bin/bash` as well.

Comment: Found the issue. My path was actually ```/bash-course/scripts``` and not ```/bash_course/scripts```

I corrected the exported path under **.profile**

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't put file extensions -- `.sh` included -- on executables. See [Commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/). The `.sh` extension is useful on a POSIX-compliant shell library, just as `.bash` should be used for shell libraries written to be used with bash, or `.py` for Python libraries (but no extension for Python _executables_ -- there's a `/usr/bin/pip`, not a `/usr/bin/pip.py`; same rule for shell)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for sharing that piece of info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. My path was actually `/bash-course/scripts` and not `/bash_course/scripts`

I corrected the exported path under **.profile**

Thanks everyone

Comment: If this is the problem, the question should be deleted -- problems caused by typographic errors are categorically off-topic.

Comment: You are right. Unable to delete the question :(